# Getting the contents between td tag using Regular expression

Tags: regex, coldfusion

Here is sample data

```
<table class="sparql" border="1"> 
<tr> <th>abstract</th></tr> 
<tr> 
  <td>
    Cologne is Germany&#39;s fourth-largest city, and is the 
    largest city both in 
    the German Federal State of North Rhine-Westphalia and within the 
    Rhine-Ruhr Metropolitan Area, one of the major European metropolitan
    areas with more than ten million inhabitants."@en
 </td> 
 </tr> 
</table>
```

and I am trying to get the contents between `<td>` tag using Regular Expression. I tried something like

```
<td>.*</td>
```

But how to discard `tags` itselef?

Comment: Use groups `<td>(.*)</td>` and then take the first one.

Comment: Regex (generally) should not be used to parse HTML. A better approach would be to use TagSoup to parse the HTML into a valid XML document and then use CF's XML functions to extract the data you need. Ben Nadel made a recent post on doing this in CF10, but I don't see any reason why you couldn't do it in older versions - you will just need to grab the TagSoup library yourself since it is not pre-installed until CF10. His blog post is here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2341-ColdFusion-10-Parsing-Dirty-HTML-Into-Valid-XML-Documents.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MisterJack points out, you need to use subexpressions to be able to refer to the match. If you're using `REReplace()`, then you can use `\1` (or `\2`, etc.) as a backreference to the match. If you're using `REFind()`, then you'll want to use it with `returnsubexpressions=true`, and it will return a `struct` with `len` and `pos` arrays for the matching values. I would do this:

```
<!--- I use "?" below because we want to be lazy rather than greedy --->
<cfset the_match = REFind(the_content, "<td>(.*?)</td>", 1, true) />

<cfdump var="#the_match#" />
```

You should see a structure with `len` and `pos` arrays. It may have only one element in each array. In order to get the match content you could then do:

```
<cfset match_content = mid(the_content, pos[i], len[i]) />
```

Hope this helps.